# Sending SMS from iPhone without notifying the iPhone user

Tags: ios, iphone

I know this isn't wise to ask but i read many articles online but didn't get any satisfactory answer. Is it possible to send sms from iphone without user's knowledge. If yes, How?

Comment: This sounds shady at best. *why* would you want to do this?

Comment: Also, even if it wasn't possibly shady, your question is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow. Once you have a specific problem, you can ask on here for help, but questions like "can I {x}" or "is there a {y} I can use" are usually closed for being off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple questions present with same content. Please search your doubt before asking questions.

Straight Answer "NO", You can't do that for privacy reasons.

Comment: Sorry, I will do that from next time, for sure. and thank you for your answer.

Comment: Such features are not available in iOS and for .00001% chance if you achieve this by any means,  the app will be rejected by Apple 100% for sure.

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, mark it as such.  Don't answer the question by saying "it is a duplicate."